# Loop click() opens file on same tab instead of a new tab

Tags: python, loops, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to iterate through a table and open files in the ***'View Attachment'*** Column in a new tab, based on whether the value in the ***'Exhibit Type'*** column is `ID Label/Location Info` or `Users Manual`.

Image of Table Data:
[image]

I am successful in opening the first file in a new tab. However, when I switch to the parent tab with the table and open the next file, the file is opened on the previous tab instead of creating a new tab. Could anyone share some guidance as to how to fix this? It would be much appreciated

This is my code so far...

```py
# Imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Function to open the link file in a new tab
def explicit_wait_xpath(my_selector):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,my_selector)))
    element.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    # Open the link in Google Chrome and maximise the window
    driver.get("https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&RequestTimeout=500&calledFromFrame=Y&application_id=UsAM7eH4uXO%2BeOEaTsEbFA%3D%3D&fcc_id=2AKW5-RH570")
    driver.maximize_window()
    parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle

    # Variables for filtering table data
    ID_LABEL = 'ID Label/Location Info'
    USERS_MANUAL = 'Users Manual'

    # Count the number of rows in the table
    rows = len(driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//table[@id='rsTable']/tbody[@id='offTblBdy']/tr"))

    # Loop through table to find correct document to open in a new tab based on the exhibit type
    for i in range(1,rows+1):
        row = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value=f'//table[@id="rsTable"]/tbody[@id="offTblBdy"]/tr[{i}]').text
        exhibit_type = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value=f'//table[@id="rsTable"]/tbody[@id="offTblBdy"]/tr[{i}]/td[3]').text

        # If the Exhibit Type column is 'ID Label/Location Info' or 'Users Manual', open the link to the file in a new tab
        if exhibit_type == ID_LABEL or exhibit_type == USERS_MANUAL:
            print(row)
            url = f'//table[@id="rsTable"]/tbody[@id="offTblBdy"]/tr[{i}]/td[2]/a'

            explicit_wait_xpath(url)

            driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
```

I've tried using `driver.get()` and passing the URL of the file, however, the website that I'm accessing only allows linking to internal documents from their website. I have a feeling that the loop may be the reason why I can't open a new tab but I'm not too sure!

Comment: What happens if you do this by hand in a browser? Selenium is just simulating the same actions.

Comment: The same actions occur when I do this by hand. Would there be any way to circumvent this?

Comment: That means the site is deliberately reusing the same window/tab. You'd need to modify their JavaScript code.

Comment: How is `explicit_wait_xpath(url)` defined?